# piecewise linear minimization equivalent to linear programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Why is

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \min\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}
& &a_i^Tx+b_i\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

equivalent to an LP

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \min
& &t\\
& \text{s.t.} & &  a_i^Tx+b_i\leq t \ \ \ \ \ \ \ i = 1,\ldots, n\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

?

I am confused about in the equivalent LP form, where is "max"? How to say both are equivalent if ignoring "max" in the constraint in the LP?

Comment: For $a_i$ of dimension 1, it is true if your piecewise linear function is convex (draw it or prove it if you are not convinced). It is a quite common linearization trick. I don't know in the case $a_i$ is a vector, it may also be true.

Comment: The "max" is implied by the fact that $t$ must be larger than *all* of the quantities $a_i^Tx+b_i$; therefore, it must be larger than their _maximum_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

---

From [here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/ee236a/lectures/pwl.pdf)

---

For example,

> minimise $f(x) = \max(3x-4,2x-1)$

is equivalent to:

> minimise t
>
> subject to
>
> $3x-4 \le t$
>
> $2x-1 \le t$

Note that

$$f(x) = 3x-4 \iff x \ge 3$$

So if we have $x = 5$, then $f(5) = 11$ and

$$11 \le t$$

$$9 \le t$$